# Downloading QGIS on Mac 12.2?

Tags: qgis, download

I'm trying to download the newest version of QGIS to my new Mac 12.2 (32 bit) system.

I get qgis-macos-pr.dmg and a TA+h+3hv.dmg.part no matter how long I wait; of course the .dmg failes with "Couldn't read file or malformed UDIF image". I tried both the newest and stable links, and get the same with both. What am I missing?

Comment: You have the official install on QGIS.org, you can install QGIS with brew too : https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/qgis#default

Comment: J.Monticolo, does a brew install end up with the same result as the official install? (See below for OSX 12.2 rejection of the official install.)

Comment: I don't know and can't test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [current stable release of QGIS for Mac OS](https://qgis.org/downloads/macos/qgis-macos-pr.dmg).

Comment: Today the download is apparently complete. But, I get the message that "it can't be checked for malicious software - update needed". And, it disabled QGIS 1.8 because "The required "osgeo [python-gdal]" module is missing".  So now I don't have even my old QGIS working 

Comment: Backups work :) My QGIS 1.8 is working again.

Comment: I've tried to report this using the bug report mechanisms on the QGIS site, but all of them use Github and that site refuses to allow me to create an account: every password I've tried is refused with "this password is compromised". So here is the only place I can report it: "“QGIS.app” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software. This software needs to be updated. Contact the developer for more information."

Comment: Have you tried to "right-click" (or ctrl-click on Mac) and select "Open" ?

Comment: Thank you, J. Monticoco, ctrl-click works. It gives me an open option then opens it, and a regular open works from then on. Whew!